# Problema con el estilo de un canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

tengo el siguiente problema: Debería de colorear en naranja el interior de un rectángulo, pero por pantalla aparece en negro. La propiedad que he encontrado que haga eso se supone que es fillStyle, pero algo falla.

Además, he de insertar un texto dentro del rectángulo, pero el texto desborda la figura y encima aparece en naranja, cuando yo no le he indicado esa propiedad y pretendo que aparezca en negro.

Muchas gracias por adelantado por la ayuda.

```js
    function dibujar() {
        if (rectangulo.getContext) {
          var contexto = rectangulo.getContext('2d');
          contexto.strokeRect(25,25,100,200);
          contexto.fillRect(25,25,100,200);
          contexto.fillStyle = "orange";
          contexto.font = "bold 22px sans-serif";
          contexto.fillText("Hola mundo", 50, 50);
        }
      }
    
    function mover() {
        var siguiente = actual + "px";
        actual += 1;
        if (actual > 900) {
        actual = 0;
        }
        rectangulo.style.left = siguiente;
        
        var intervalo = 18;
        setTimeout(mover, intervalo);
        }

    function iniciar() {
        dibujar();
        var rectangulo = document.getElementById("rectangulo");
        rectangulo.style.position = "absolute";
        actual = 0;
        mover();
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HLC-Tarea</title>
</head>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<body onload="iniciar()">
    <canvas id="rectangulo" height="200px" width="400px"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agrega lo siguiente en la funcion `iniciar` debajo de la línea donde defines `rectangulo` (`var rectangulo`):

```javascript
rectangulo.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
```

para conseguir el fondo naranja del rectángulo.

Y cambia estos dos valores:

```javascript
contexto.strokeRect(25,25,100,200);
contexto.fillRect(25,25,100,200);
```

por estos:

```javascript
contexto.strokeRect(25, 25, 200, 35);
contexto.fillRect(25, 25, 200, 35);
```

para que te quede una cosa así:

```js
function dibujar() {
  if (rectangulo.getContext) {
    var contexto = rectangulo.getContext('2d');
    contexto.strokeRect(25, 25, 200, 35);
    contexto.fillRect(25, 25, 200, 35);
    contexto.fillStyle = "orange";
    contexto.font = "bold 22px sans-serif";
    contexto.fillText("Hola mundo", 50, 50);
  }
}

function mover() {
  var siguiente = actual + "px";
  actual += 1;
  if (actual > 900) {
    actual = 0;
  }
  rectangulo.style.left = siguiente;

  var intervalo = 18;
  setTimeout(mover, intervalo);
}

function iniciar() {
  dibujar();
  var rectangulo = document.getElementById("rectangulo");
  rectangulo.style.position = "absolute";
  rectangulo.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
  actual = 0;
  mover();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HLC-Tarea</title>
</head>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<body onload="iniciar()">
    <canvas id="rectangulo" height="200px" width="400px"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

A partir de aqui haz las modicaciones que creas oportunas para conseguir el efecto final que necesitas.

Comment: Buenas @masterguru

Una vez más, le doy las gracias por su ayuda, porque, efectivamente, con esta solución, valga la redundancia, se soluciona el problema que tenía.

Comment: Quizas te conviene más la solución de @PabloLozano, echale un ojo a ver si te va mejor por si acaso

Comment: Ambas respuestas están muy bien @masterguru.

Sin embargo, ¿cómo podría añadirle al rectángulo un borde negro? ¿Lo establezco con rectangulo.style.border en la función iniciar?

Comment: Lo mejor que puedes hacer, para realizar pruebas, es usar este enlace donde ya está puesto tu código y realizar las modificaciones que desees y luego apretar el botón RUN y así vas viendo como queda:  https://jsfiddle.net/p5orhuyb/

Comment: Estupendo. Muchas gracias una vez más :)

Comment: Aun así, veo que el canvas viene sin border por defecto, y con eso del rectangulo no consigo meterlo, pero si le agrego el estilo directamente en el elemento <canvas> si que funciona, es decir:  `<canvas id="rectangulo" height="200px" width="400px" style="border:100px solid #000000;"></canvas>` ... seguro que con javascript tambien se puede, pero ahora no doy con ello

Comment: Perdon, si que funciona, puedes ponerlo asi tambien:  `rectangulo.style.border = "100px solid black";`

Comment: Entendido! Es que había algo que no estaba definiendo correctamente, y en este caso eran los valores del borde. Muchas gracias oootra vez :D

Answer (score 3):

Analicemos la función `dibujar`:

```
function dibujar() {
    if (rectangulo.getContext) {
      var contexto = rectangulo.getContext('2d'); //toma el contexto del canvas
      contexto.strokeRect(25,25,100,200); //dibuja un rectángulo
      contexto.fillRect(25,25,100,200); //colorea el interior

//cambiamos el color a usar de negro (por defecto) a naranja
      contexto.fillStyle = "orange"; 
      contexto.font = "bold 22px sans-serif";
      contexto.fillText("Hola mundo", 50, 50); //escribimos texto con el nuevo color

    }
  }
```

Por tanto estás definiendo el color a usar demasiado tarde, **después** de hacer el rectángulo. Si arreglamos esta parte tendremos:

```js
function dibujar() {
  if (rectangulo.getContext) {
    const contexto = rectangulo.getContext('2d');
    //primero seleccionamos el color naranja
    contexto.fillStyle = "orange";
    
    //contexto.strokeRect(25,25,200,100); innecesario
    
    contexto.fillRect(25,25,200,100); //corregimos el tamaño, más ancho y menos alto
    
    //cambiamos a negro
    contexto.fillStyle = "black";
    contexto.font = "bold 22px sans-serif";
    contexto.fillText("Hola mundo", 50, 50);
  }
}

const rectangulo = document.getElementById('rectangulo');
dibujar();
```

```html
<canvas id="rectangulo"></canvas>
```

Por otro lado, estás usando setTimeout para mover, lo que no es una buena idea: los navegadores tienen hoy día una función específica para repintar en cada refresco: [`window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame):

```js
let posicionX = 0;
const canvas = document.getElementById('rectangulo');
const contexto = canvas.getContext('2d');

function dibujar() {
  contexto.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // borramos todo
  //primero seleccionamos el color naranja
  contexto.fillStyle = "orange";

  //contexto.strokeRect(25,25,200,100); innecesario

  contexto.fillRect(25 + posicionX,25,200,100); //corregimos el tamaño, más ancho y menos alto

  //cambiamos a negro
  contexto.fillStyle = "black";
  contexto.font = "bold 22px sans-serif";
  contexto.fillText("Hola mundo", 50 + posicionX, 50);
  posicionX = (posicionX+1) % 100 ;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(dibujar)
}

dibujar();
```

```html
<canvas id="rectangulo"></canvas>
```

Comment: Buenas @Pablo

Pues has dado en el clavo. El problema estaba en el momento en el que estaba declarando el color.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.